# Window Layout management keyboard shortcut

Tags: display, windows, shortcut, window-manager

- I have 3 screens like in the image below and exactly 2 windows split in half in each.
- I want to set up a keyboard shortcut to take the given window to one of those 6 spaces.
- I prefer a modal shortcut like Moom app. Ctrl+` takes to a mode where I can type 1 through 6 to take the window to that positioning.
- What app can I use to set up this configuration, and (preferably) only this configuration (and not so much more shortcuts)?

I use the Moom app right now but too many keystrokes each time to move between displays and then to go to the specific half position.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I found out about [Rectangle](https://github.com/rxhanson/Rectangle) from this site
- I [engaged with the developer on Github](https://github.com/rxhanson/Rectangle/discussions/476) and offered to make this change
- He did the change on his other product, Hookshot and reported back
- I bought the license to [Hookshot](https://hookshot.app/) and configured it thus in custom shortcuts
  [image]
- Overall, excellent work in both [Rectange](https://github.com/rxhanson/Rectangle) and [Hookshot](https://hookshot.app/), by the developer. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the (commercial) [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/)? It can do just what you ask, as illustrated in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQs_YMzKyl8), and many more things related to multi-monitor setups. Simply assign it a key combination.

Other options may be [Stay](https://cordlessdog.com/stay/), [Display Maid](https://funk-isoft.com/display-maid.html), [Mosaic](https://setapp.com/apps/mosaic), etc.